# Is using ng-init for bind once valid in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-init

i have a collection of values whose structure lets assume to be

```
var a = [{id:1, value:12, name="one"}, {id:2, value:34, name="two"},...]
```

i wanted to display this in a series of controls so that user can change the values. but with that i  also wanted to display original values which obviously shoudn't change.
i found out a way that is working and my code is something like this using ng-init

```
 <div ng-repeat="p in a">
  <div class="control-group" ng-if="p.value>0">
    <label class="control-label" ng-bind="p.name"></label>
    <div class="controls controls-row" ng-init="v=p.value">
      <input class="span1" value="{{v}}"/>
      <input type="number" ng-model="p.value" class="span2" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

being a complete newbie in angularjs i dont know what implications this might have as i have very little experience in thinking about $watch and performance.

**Is it ok to do so?**

Comment: would suggest just copying the whole array if you want to keep it...`var b= angular.copy(a)`. Can then match indexes for markup

Comment: @charlietfl - yes my first attempt was that. but still angular keeps watching the values when i know they wont be changing.

Comment: don't understand last comment

Comment: at first i did that.. to copy the array and then using it to bind values. But still if i cope an array using angular.copy() it creates a deep copy and hence angular js will continue to look for changes

Comment: you keep saying the same thing....and it's not making sense. A demo would help that presents your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but with that i also wanted to display original values which obviously shoudn't change.

Use `angular.copy(/* array */)`. It will create new copy (instance) of old array.

BTW `a` collection must be defined as `$scope.a`

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/819/)**</kbd>

Comment: this is not my question. deep copying an array and then displaying a value is ok but what about using ng-init?

Comment: can you post your `watch` method? I don't undersend `ng-init="v=p.value` goal. it does nothing, but creates new value `v`

Comment: i have no watch method, the value created here is what im using later to display <input class="span1" value="{{v}}"/>

Comment: but you can write: `value="{{p.value}}"` its the same. Do you want to prevent deep watch on `p` by creating new `v`? it will not help you, in your case v = p.value.

Comment: yes i want to prevent deep watch. and it is not equal to value={{p.value}} because if i use {{p.value}} then if the p.value changes later value of the input changes

Comment: so write `v = angular.copy(p.value)`